# How do I ignore the time zone when parsing with Joda's DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime, datetime-format

I'm trying to parse rubbish date values out of IPTC metadata. The format is *supposed* to be `yyyyMMdd` but in some situations it isn't. A particular value I have found is `"Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 AEDT 2016"`.

If I try to parse this using Joda's `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
              .parseLocalDate("Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 AEDT 2016");
```

This gives me an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 AEDT 2016" is malformed at "AEDT 2016"
```

I have tried the following zone symbols:

- z
- zz
- Z
- ZZ
- ZZZ

I realise that the docs do say that `DateTimeFormatter` can't parse time zones. I also realise that these short time zone names are ambiguous. But in this situation I'm only trying to get out a `LocalDate`, so all I *really* want is the month, day and year. (Notice how the hour, minute and second are also zero?)

I would rather *not* have to regex crap out of the middle of the string before passing it off if possible, because the thing I'm passing this formatter off to expects a `DateTimeFormatter` at present.

Is there a way to specify some kind of arbitrary pattern of junk to throw away when parsing? I can't seem to find it in the API, but that doesn't necessarily mean it isn't there.

Comment: Did you try quoted text i.e. `forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'AEDT' yyyy")` and would that work for you?

Comment: That works for this specific example, but then what if it's AEST or PST or PDT or MST... (interestingly, UTC works with the existing code.)

Comment: The problem is not that it cannot parse the date, it's just that it doesn't recognize `AEDT` as a valid timezone.  Replace it with `EST` or `PST` and it works just fine.  Given that you've already identified the format in order to parse it with this specific `DateTimeFormat`, how much harder can it be to do a simple regex replace and give it something it recognizes, since you're just going to ignore it anyway?

Comment: I was able to do a regex, but it's mangling the resulting lump of code back into a DateTimeFormatter which is hard. My other approach (the one I posted as an answer) is slightly cleaner because it puts the lump of code inside a Joda class which can at least be slotted directly into a DateTimeFormatterBuilder.    PST and EST (and CST and MST) are also "special" zones, in that various standards (e.g. email) say that they are unambiguous. So even if they work, maybe they're the only ones that work?

Answer (score 3):

I'll post my own message workaround in the meantime, which uses a mix of existing format patterns plus a custom parser to throw away the time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ")
    .append(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("Z").getPrinter(), new DiscardTimeZoneSymbolParser())
    .appendPattern(" yyyy")
    .toFormatter();

LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate("Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 AEDT 2016");
```

And then:

```
public class DiscardTimeZoneSymbolParser implements DateTimeParser {
    @Override
    public int estimateParsedLength() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int parseInto(DateTimeParserBucket bucket, @NonNls String text, int position) {
        for (int positionFromStart = 0; positionFromStart < 4; positionFromStart++, position++) {
            boolean match;
            if (position >= text.length()) {
                match = false;
            } else {
                @NonNls
                char ch = text.charAt(position);
                match = ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z';
            }

            if (!match) {
                if (positionFromStart >= 3) { // require 3 characters
                    return position;
                } else {
                    return ~position;
                }
            }
        }

        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for your efforts but will you be prepared for any other unexpected input??? You could also use `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` (or even my library Time4J which has arguably the best parse engine) and encapsulate it inside your custom `DateTimeParser` and use following pattern or similar: "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss [z ] yyyy". Note the square brackets indicating an optional information. If your data contain in most cases the format "yyyyMMdd" then you will also need a multi format pattern approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parsing facilities in `java.text`:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
df.setLenient(false);
Date date = df.parse("Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 AEDT 2016");
```

and then transform the `java.util.Date` in the Joda `LocalDate`. Note that:

- neither Date nor LocalDate have a timezone: Date is UTC, and LocalDate refers to a Chronology, not to an instant
- I specified the Locale for the parser, but you may need to use the default locale of the JMV, or any other locale depending on your input

Comment: I think if I were going to avoid Joda then java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter would be much better than java.text.SimpleDateFormat. But the problem here is that it would require awkward wrapping to get it back into a DateTimeFormatter so that I can use it with the existing framework. :(

Comment: It does, but last time it took about 3 months and arguably the work isn't finished on that round yet.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is the huge interface of `DateTimeFormatter` which prevents you writing your own implementation or decorator easily.

> ...the thing I'm passing this formatter off to expects a `DateTimeFormatter` at present.

Is it out of the question to refactor the framework (the "thing") like so:

Step 1: Create a new interface:

```
public interface LocalDateTimeParser {
    LocalDate parseLocalDate(String text);
}
```

Step 2: Create an adaptor:

```
public final class DateTimeFormatterAdapter implements LocalDateTimeParser {

    private final DateTimeFormatter adaptee;

    public DateTimeFormatterAdapter(DateTimeFormatter adaptee){
        this.adaptee = adaptee;
    }

    public LocalDate parseLocalDate(String text){
        return adaptee.parseLocalDate(text);
    }
}
```

Step 2: Reference `LocalDateTimeParser` in your framework where only local parsing is required and wrap the existing `DateTimeFormatter` in an adapter.

Step 3: Now you are free to write your own `LocalDateTimeParser` implementation with regex pre processing to strip the timezone and pass the rest to a `DateTimeFormatter`.